# Appended element click function is not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I attach click event to appended element by `$('body').on('click')`. But if I click **id one** two times, it also alert two times when its appended element click.

If I attach like this `$('body').off().on("click")`, the last appended element click can alert only *(if I click id one first and then click id two,then id one appended element click can't alert)*.

How can I attach click event for every appended element to alert once ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  test.init();
})

var test = {
  init : function() {
    $("#one").on("click",function(){
      test.appendOne();
    });
    $("#two").on("click",function(){
      test.appendTwo();
    });
  },
  appendOne: function() {
    $("<button class='one-after'>").append("<h1>One</h1>").appendTo("body");    
    $('body').on("click",'.one-after',function() {
      alert("clickedOne");
    });
  },
  appendTwo: function() {
    $("<button class='two-after'>").append("<h1>Two</h1>").appendTo("body");    
    $('body').on("click",'.two-after',function() {
      alert("clickedTwo");
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="one">One</button>
<button id="two">Two</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use selector children() which is a selector on every first level children of the body element (see documentation reference at https://api.jquery.com/children/)

So your code would become :

```
$('body').children().on("click")
```

Answer (score 0):

with a slight modification, add the event directly to the appended object as below:

```
  $("<button class='one-after'>").append("<h1>One</h1>").appendTo("body")    
        .on("click",function() {
          alert("clickedOne"); })
```

you can repeat this pattern for the other one

Answer (score 0):

That happen since every time you click the button, you bind a new event on the `body`.

You already are using event delegation, you only have to bind the event once and every new element will have an event *"attached"* to it. Move your event binding inside your `init`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  test.init();
})

var test = {
  init : function() {
    $('body').on("click",'.one-after',function() {
      alert("clickedOne");
    }).on("click",'.two-after',function() {
      alert("clickedTwo");
    });
    
    $("#one").on("click",function(){
      test.appendOne();
    });
    $("#two").on("click",function(){
      test.appendTwo();
    });
  },
  appendOne: function() {
    $("<button class='one-after'>").append("<h1>One</h1>").appendTo("body");    
  },
  appendTwo: function() {
    $("<button class='two-after'>").append("<h1>Two</h1>").appendTo("body");    
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="one">One</button>
<button id="two">Two</button>
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? I might have misexplained something.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply change these two lines:

```
$("<button class='one-after'>").append("<h1>One</h1>").appendTo("body");    
$('body').on("click",'.one-after',function() {
```

to (chain appendTo with on. Remove the event delegation):

```
$("<button class='one-after'>").append("<h1>One</h1>").appendTo("body").on("click",function() {
```

Instead of creating a delegation click event handler on the body you can simply add the click event to each element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    test.init();
})

var test = {
    init : function() {
        $("#one").on("click",function(){
            test.appendOne();
        });
        $("#two").on("click",function(){
            test.appendTwo();
        });
    },
    appendOne: function() {
        $("<button class='one-after'>").append("<h1>One</h1>").appendTo("body").on("click",function() {
            alert("clickedOne");
        });
    },
    appendTwo: function() {
        $("<button class='two-after'>").append("<h1>Two</h1>").appendTo("body").on("click",function() {
            alert("clickedTwo");
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="one">One</button>
<button id="two">Two</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's .one() variant:

```
$("#one").one("click",function(){
  test.appendOne();
});
```

This will fire only once. http://api.jquery.com/one/